# AlertDialog.Builder dynamically setMessage

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

I am trying to dynamically set message to AlertDialog.Builder , 
but when i run the app , no message is shown. I want the message to be changed according to the text the user types on some editText widgets.
Any advice appreciated.

```
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
private CharSequence alertMessage;
    // set AlertMessage
public CharSequence setAlertMessage() {
    if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγόρι") &&
            editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κορίτσι") &&
            editText2.getText().toString().equals("ένας άντρας") &&
            editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναίκα")) {
        alertMessage = ("Συγχαρηρήρια! Πάτησε ΟΚ για να\nπροχωρήσεις στην επόμενη διεπαφή");
    } else if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγορι") &&
            editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κοριτσι") &&
            editText2.getText().toString().equals("ενας αντρας") &&
            editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναικα")) {
        alertMessage = ("Μάλλον ξέχασες τους τόνους!\nΞαναπροσπάθησε");
    } else if (editText2.getText().toString().equals("o άντρας") || editText2.getText().toString().equals("ο αντρας") &&
            editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναίκα") || editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναικα")) {
        alertMessage = ("Μάλλον ξέχασες τις αόριστες αντωνυμίες\n(ενας , μια)\nΠάτησε ΟΚ για να ξαναπροσπαθήσεις");
    }
    return alertMessage;
}
dialog = builder.create();
        basicsBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγόρι") &&
                    editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κορίτσι") &&
                    editText2.getText().toString().equals("ένας άντρας") &&
                    editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναίκα")) {
                dialog.show();
            }
            else if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγορι") &&
                    editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κοριτσι") &&
                    editText2.getText().toString().equals("ενας αντρας") &&
                    editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναικα")) {
                dialog.show();
            }
            else if (editText2.getText().toString().equals("o άντρας") || editText2.getText().toString().equals("ο αντρας") &&
                    editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναίκα") || editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναικα")) {
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Έκανες κάποιο λάθος!Ξαναπροσπάθησε.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
builder.setMessage(setAlertMessage());
```

Comment: You didn't call .create().show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you built your dialog you have to create them by method `create()` from `Builder` class and after that you have to display it by method `show()` from `Dialog` class.

You have to change way how you display dialog after click on:

```
 basicsBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγόρι") &&
                editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κορίτσι") &&
                editText2.getText().toString().equals("ένας άντρας") &&
                editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναίκα")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).setMessage(setAlertMessage()).create().show();
        }
        else if (editText0.getText().toString().equals("το αγορι") &&
                editText1.getText().toString().equals("το κοριτσι") &&
                editText2.getText().toString().equals("ενας αντρας") &&
                editText3.getText().toString().equals("μια γυναικα")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).setMessage(setAlertMessage()).create().show();
        }
        else if (editText2.getText().toString().equals("o άντρας") || editText2.getText().toString().equals("ο αντρας") &&
                editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναίκα") || editText3.getText().toString().equals("η γυναικα")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).setMessage(setAlertMessage()).create().show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Έκανες κάποιο λάθος!Ξαναπροσπάθησε.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: check now you have to create and show dialog every time when you click on button

Comment: change YourActivity -> to class name of your Activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71673/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and--).

Comment: When some solution is right you should accept it to inform others that your issue is already resolved